# Apply function to part of list python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to write a function called compress, which takes in a list, two indices and a function, and spits out the same list with the two elements specified "compressed" together with the given function. I have implemented this with copy.deepcopy as follows:

```
import copy
def compress(l, i, j, f):
   r = copy.deepcopy(l)
   r[i] = f(r[i], r[j])
   r.pop(j)
   return r
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this? Or perhaps a more "pure" functional way?

Comment: Do you need to deep copy? What's wrong with just a normal copy (`l.copy()`)? Other than that (and using more explicit variable names) this is fine.

Comment: IDK about *pythonic*, but naming parameters with more than one letter wouldn't hurt...

Comment: Can you put two sample lists, and then a sample output please, there are many ways to interpret  the word 'compressed'

Comment: Yeah good point with naming parameters, I am very used to writing code only I read. Thanks for the heads up. I guess I was asking if this could be implemented with tools like "filter" or "map", but I didn't word my question very clearly. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The functional way would be to rebuild a new list instead of mutating. To make things simpler it can be written as a generator function, with a simple utility wrapper building the list from the generator:

```
def itercompress(source, first_index, second_index, compress_func):
    compressed = compress_func(source[first_index], source[second_index])
    for index, value in enumerate(source):
        if index == first_index:
            yield compressed
        elif index == second_index:
            continue
        else:
           yield value

def compress(source, first_index, second_index, compress_func):
    return list(itercompress(source, first_index, second_index, compress_func)
```

Not sure this will yield better performances though... Except for the probably useless `deepcopy` (well, depends if the compression function does nasty things to its arguments but then I'd say it's a programming error from the compression function's author), your code just lacks proper naming to be pythonic ("pythonic" doesn't mean "fancy" nor "smart" nor even "elegant", but "correct", "simple", and "readable"):

```
def compress(source, first_index, second_index, compress_func):
   result = source[:] # shallow copy
   result[first_index] = compress_func(result[first_index], result[last_index])
   result.pop(last_index)
   return result
```